# How to add click event to google maps marker while mapping array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
## Mounted function ##
```

> I manage to get my markers to show, but struggle to add a click event
> to each marker.

```
    async mounted() {
        try {
          const googlenter code heree = await gmapsInit();
          const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          const map = new google.maps.Map(this.$el);
        enter code here
          geocoder.geocode({ address: "Salt Lake City" }, (results, status) => {
            if (status !== "OK" || !results[0]) {
              throw new Error(status);
            }
    
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
          });
    
          const markers = this.allListings.map(marker => {
            new google.maps.Marker({
              ...marker,
              map,
              title: marker.businessName
            });
```

> This is where I am wanting to add the click event

```
            marker.addListener("click", toggleBounce);
            
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      },
    };
    </script>
```